# How to do OptionContext parsing on an instance?

Tags: command-line-arguments, instance-variables, glib, vala

I'm trying to get options parsing using `OptionContext` to work.

My code so far:

```
public class Options : GLib.Object {

    public string option_output = "";

    public Options () {
    }

    public void parse (string args[]) throws OptionError {

        // string option_output;

        const OptionEntry[] options = {
            { "output", 'o', 0, OptionArg.FILENAME, 
        ref option_output, "file name for encoded output (required);", 
        "FILE" },
        {null}
        };
        var opt_context = new OptionContext ("- vpng2theora");
        opt_context.set_help_enabled (true);
        opt_context.add_main_entries (options, null);
        unowned string[] temp_args = args;
        foreach (var arg in temp_args) {
            print ("arg: %s\n", arg);
        }
        opt_context.parse (ref temp_args);
        print (option_output);
    }

}


int main (string[] args) {
    Options opts = new Options ();
    opts.parse (args);
    return 0;
}
```

As it stands this doesn't compile because:

```
error: Value must be constant
```

If I remove the `const` altogether:

```
OptionEntry[] options = {
    { "output", 'o', 0, OptionArg.FILENAME, 
    ref option_output, "file name for encoded output (required);", 
    "FILE" },
    {null}
};
```

The error is:

```
error: Expected array element, got array initializer list
```

The only way I can get around this problem is declaring the `option_output` as a `static` class field, but that defeats the purpose of instantiation.

Is there any way to have the OptionContext parsing work on an instance instead of a static class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will work:

```
public class Options : GLib.Object {

    public string option_output = "";

    public bool parse (ref unowned string[] args) {
        var options = new OptionEntry[2];
        options[0] = { "output", 'o', 0, OptionArg.FILENAME, 
        ref option_output, "file name for encoded output (required);", 
        "FILE" };
        options[1] = {null};

        var opt_context = new OptionContext ("- vpng2theora");
        opt_context.set_help_enabled (true);
        opt_context.add_main_entries (options, null);
        foreach (var arg in args) {
            print ("arg: %s\n", arg);
        }
        bool result= true;
        try {
            opt_context.parse (ref args);
            print( option_output );
        } catch {
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }

}

int main (string[] args) {
    Options opts = new Options ();
    if (!opts.parse (ref args)) { return -1; }
    return 0;
}
```

The options parsing will remove the optional arguments and then you can parse the required ones, such as the filenames to process. That's why I've kept the original `args` passed to the parse function. So you will get a cleaned set of `args` back, that you can then parse again for the required arguments. I found ["CLI design: Putting flags to good use"](http://julipedia.meroh.net/2013/08/cli-design-putting-flags-to-good-use.html) a useful read.

`options` is an array of structs. I don't understand well enough why setting the size of the array is necessary, but it works for me.