# How does string interpolation / string templates work?

Tags: vala, string-interpolation, genie

[@lf_araujo asked in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39052435/how-to-sort-a-dict-in-genie):

```
var dic = new dict of string, string
dic["z"] = "23"
dic["abc"] = "42"
dic["pi"] = "3.141"
for k in sorted_string_collection (dic.keys)
    print (@"$k: $(dic[k])")
```

> What is the function of @ in print(@ ... ) and lines_add(@ ...)?

As this is applicable to both Genie and Vala, I thought it would be better suited as a stand-alone question.

The conceptual question is:

How does string interpolation work in Vala and Genie?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two options for [string interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation) in Vala and Genie:

1. [printf-style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string) functions:

   ```
   var name = "Jens Mühlenhoff";
   var s = string.printf ("My name is %s, 2 + 2 is %d", name, 2 + 2);
   ```

   This works using varargs, you have to pass multiple arguments with the correct types to the varargs function (in this case `string.printf`).
2. string templates:

   ```
   var name = "Jens Mühlenhoff";
   var s = @"My name is $name, 2 + 2 is $(2 + 2)";
   ```

   This works using "compiler magic".

   A template string starts with `@"` (rather then `"` which starts a normal string).

   Expressions in the template string start with `$` and are enclosed with `()`. The brackets are unneccesary when the expression doesn't contain white space like `$name` in the above example.

   Expressions are evaluated before they are put into the string that results from the string template. For expressions that aren't of type `string` the compiler tries to call `.to_string ()`, so you don't have to explicitly call it. In the `$(2 + 2)` example the expression `2 + 2` is evaluated to `4` and then `4.to_string ()` is called with will result in `"4"` which can then be put into the string template.

PS: I'm using Vala syntax here, just remove the `;`s to convert to Genie.

Comment: Just to note that albeit Genie does not officially has the ; at the end of the lines, the compiler does not complain about it.